# How to access custom response values from a page script?

Tags: next.js

This might sound like a silly question but I have really tried everything I could to figure it out. I am creating a variable and adding it to my response object in custom Express server file like so:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.locals.user = req.user || null;
   handle(req, res);
});
```

Now I want to access this **res.locals.user** object from all of my pages, i.e. *index.js*, *about.js*, etc., in order to keep a tab on the active session's user credentials. It's got to be possible some way, right?

P.S.: Reading some thread on the NextJS Github page, I tried accessing it from my props object as `this.props.user` but it keeps returning null even when a server-side `console.log` shows non-null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `res` object is available on the server as a parameter to `getInitialProps`. So, with the server code you have above, you can do

```
static async getInitialProps({res}) {
    return { user: res.locals.user }
}
```

to make it available as `this.props.user`.